# Query to pickup certain criteria records

Tags: sql, sybase

I have following table data

```
ID         Type Code     Opt    Line    Status

26985444    1   100        1       1    S0
26987422    1   25         1       1    S0
26987422    1   25         2       1    S1
26987422    1   25         2       2    S2
26987422    4   25         2       3    S0
26987422    2   30         1       1    S1
26987422    2   30         1       2    S2
26987422    2   30         1       3    S0
26987422    3   35         1       1    S0
26985333    1   75         1       1    S0
26985000    1   55         1       1    S0
26985000    1   65         1       1    S0
```

Out of above I need to select ONLY following records

```
26985444    1   100 1   1   S0
26985333    1   75  1   1   S0
```

How can I write SQL query to this.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand -- what determines the criteria for selection?  First and last record of a table?  There's no guarantee of an order without explicitly defining it.

Comment: Thanks for response. Not the first and last record. (I have edited the sample record for not being misled). here ID and Code should be unique with combination and along as well. Hope make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am interpreting your question as finding `ID`s that only appear once in the data.

You can do this with aggregation, looking for the singletons:

```
select ID, min(Type) as Type, min(Code) as Code, min(Opt) as Opt,
       min(Line) as Line, min(Status) as Status
from t
group by id
having count(*) = 1;
```

If your version of Sybase supports window functions:

```
select ID, Type, Code, Opt, Line, Status
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The only sorting I see in your above table is if you were to sort by the `Code` field while it's converted to a `char()`.  Here's a guess at what you might be looking for using `max()` and `min()`:

```
select y.* 
from yourtable y
  join (
    select max(cast(Code as char(3))) maxCode,
      min(cast(Code as char(3))) minCode
    from yourtable
    ) t on y.code = t.maxCode or y.code = t.minCode
```

- [Condensed Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e01b/1)